# PHP Fatal error

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

For some reason Apache/PHP is throwing these errors in the error_log. I can't figure out what is causing it?

```
[Wed May 06 16:39:33.056497 2015] [:error] [pid 14857:tid 140714977302272] [client 165.196.202.10:3143] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot find save handler '/var/lib/php/wsdlcache' in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://web.$
[Wed May 06 16:43:34.248044 2015] [:error] [pid 15111:tid 140715103180544] [client 163.248.244.189:25966] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot find save handler 'tcp://74.221.216.88:11211?persistent=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_i$
[Wed May 06 16:45:04.160496 2015] [:error] [pid 15174:tid 140715375916800] [client 163.248.244.76:32613] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot find save handler 'tcp://74.221.216.88:11211?persistent=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_in$
[Wed May 06 16:45:33.577941 2015] [:error] [pid 15302:tid 140715134650112] [client 162.127.23.29:52057] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot find save handler 'tcp://74.221.216.88:11211?persistent=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_int$
[Wed May 06 16:47:04.304594 2015] [:error] [pid 15365:tid 140714998281984] [client 198.236.95.97:22866] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot find save handler 'tcp://74.221.216.88:11211?persistent=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_int$
[Wed May 06 16:50:31.683150 2015] [:error] [pid 15680:tid 140715218568960] [client 206.208.218.40:40735] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot find save handler 'tcp://74.221.216.88:11211?persistent=1&amp;timeout=1&amp;retry_in$
```

According to "php -i | grep session" the same handler for sessions is right.

```
session.save_handler => memcache => memcache
session.save_path => tcp://74.221.216.88:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=10 => tcp://74.221.216.88:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=10
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
OS: CentOS 7 64Bit
Http: Apache 2.4 event mpm
PHP: php-zts

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that the memcache module is loaded by PHP?  This error could happen if memcache is not loaded.

Comment: Yep, it's loaded. 
[root@web httpd]# php -m | grep memcache
memcache

Answer (score 0):

Check whether is memcache daemon is running and port 11211 is listening and awailable by filrewall. Also you should check memcache module in PHP(loaded or not)

Comment: memcache module is loaded, shows in php -m, and the configuring is set correction in php -i as shown above. The weird thing is, is that this error isn't all the time. 1000's of visitors are using the site just fine, but this error keeps showing up several times a day.